# Set warning as error in eclipse juno IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, warnings

I want to set warning as error in my Eclipse Juno IDE.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TryRefactoring try1 = new TryRefactoring();//warning shown here
    } 
}
```

but I want to set this warning show me as error in my IDE ?

Comment: what is TryRefactoring class contains. Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: public class TryRefactoring {

 public void getPrint() 
 {
  
  System.out.println("i want to refactor");
  
 }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse if you right click on your Project in the Package Explorer, then go to properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings. You can then manually change which compiler findings appear as warnings/errors/ignored etc...

Answer (score 2):

I will update @Matthew Ertel's answer to April, 2021.

Menu Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Error/Warnings.